# Can we restrict the movement of the multivalued field in a schema

Tags: 2011, schema

Is there any way to restrict the movement of multivalued field in a schema.

Can we configure it in any schema.

Comment: It would seem to me that if you want to impose such restrictions, you might be better off defining two or more fields instead of one multi-value field.

Comment: @Quirijn. Thank you. Here the Max occurance is uncertain.

Comment: Why not have 2 multi-value fields then? If the values are not interchangeable they should not be in the same field together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That functionality is not out of the box. You'll need a UI extension for that.
It looks like you need to modify the default behaviour of the Compoennt View editor (based on other questions you post in here). I already pointed out the open source project that takes care of modifying the behaviour of the Component View Editor. I am going to encourage you again to look at it:

[FIELD BEHAVIOUR INJECTION](https://code.google.com/p/tridion-field-behavior-injection/)

I am posting a video with an explanation on how that project works. Will put the link here shortly.